# Facebook notifications - need permission or not?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is what I'm seeing in the docs:

```
Apps can send notifications to any existing user that has authorized the app. No special or extended permission is required.
```

Okay, sounds good. I'm using the JS SDK and here is what I'm trying to do:

```
FB.api('/me/notifications?access_token=' + window.accessToken + '&href=test&template=test', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
});
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
"(#200) The "manage_notifications" permission is required in order to query the user's notifications."
```

I have tried replacing the href parameter with my app's real domain. Using my facebook ID instead of "/me/" makes no difference either. HELP!

I HAVE tried adding the manage_notifications permission (and still doesn't work...), but my question is why does it say the opposite in the docs?

**EDIT:** Went to PHP:

```
<?php 

include_once('sdk/facebook.php');

$user = $_POST['user'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '609802022365238';
$config['secret'] = '71afdf0dcbb5f00739cfaf4aff4301e7';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$facebook->setAccessToken($config['appId'].'|'.$config['secret']);

$href = 'href';

$params = array(
        'href' => $href,
        'template' => $message,
    );


$facebook->api('/' . $user . '/notifications/', 'POST', $params);

?>
```

**EDIT 2:** After a silly logic mistake it now works :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To send a notification you must use application access token - `appid|appsecret`, so you should send it server side and execute via AJAX call. PHP example:

```
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$facebook->setAccessToken($config['appId'].'|'.$config['secret']);

$user = 'userid';
$message = 'message';
$href = 'href';

$params = array(
        'href' => $href,
        'template' => $message,
    );

$facebook->api('/' . $user . '/notifications/', 'post', $params);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/

Comment: I see. I will try it and see what's up. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'm not getting any errors. The bad news is that it's not working :) I tried using try-catch, but nothing. Any idea how to see what went wrong?

Comment: You are sending a request to user, who authorized the application? Try replace the last line with `$send = $facebook->api('/' . $user . '/notifications/', 'post', $params); var_dump($send);` It's work for me and var_dump return `array(1) { ["success"]=> bool(true) }`